# No name was provided for external module 'ngx-cookie-service' in output.globals – guessing 'ngxCookieService'

Tags: node.js, ng-packagr, ngx-cookie-service

Using ng-packagr I got this error during the build:

```
No name was provided for external module 'ngx-cookie-service' in output.globals – guessing 'ngxCookieService'
```

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "C:/projets/promaides/MenuEntite/dist/menu-top",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "@ngx-translate/core": "ngx-translate-core",
      "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "ngx-translate/http-loader",
      "ngx-cookie-service": "ngx-cookie-service"
    }
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "ngx-cookie-service"
  ]
}
```

Maybe it is not the correct way to use **whitelistedNonPeerDependencies** or **umdModuleIds** with ngx-cookie-service

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr

Comment: https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled over a similar problem.

Just read the output of your build:
`guessing 'ngxCookieService´`

So in your ng-package.json it should be:
`"ngx-cookie-service": "ngxCookieService"`

That should do the trick!